# How to write very high/low notes in G/F clef?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, beginner

Standard piano music sheets contain G and F clefs, which can display comfortably (without using a lot of ledger lines) around 48 keys C2-C6.

I wonder how people write the very high/low notes, i.e., C1 or C8? Thanks.

Comment: In practice, I've seen a *lot* of professionally engraved and sold piano sheet music use a lot of ledger lines to denote C1 (often but not always with C2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the Octave Sign that can indicate octave up or down for the really high and low notes. So, for instance, you can if you want to notate a note an octave up from.

So instead of this...

[image: Example 1]

This

[image: Example 2]

Comment: 15 rather than 16! va for up, vb for down.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use a transposed G or F clef:

[image: Treble 8]

Comment: This might be "correct" according to some reference (which nobody stated) but it's living dangerously to use *only* a transposed clef for keyboard instruments which *don't* usually use them, like piano. And for instruments like celesta that *do* use octave transpositions, the number is often omitted from the clef because everybody knows what the notation means. For example neither Finale nor Sibelius (both professional-standard notation programs) add the "8" to guitar notation by default, though of course they play back the score an octave lower than written.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred method depends on the instrument in question.  The violin and the clarinet, for examples, are accustomed to playing a couple octaves' worth of ledger lines above the trebleclef.  Cello parts may have a stack of ledger lines, or they may jump from bass to tenor or even treble clef, or get annotated "8va" .

I once had to explain to a music major (underclass) that, unlike a piano score, woodwinds did not want to see notes progressing down from the treble to the bass clef, but rather just use ledger lines below the staff :-) .

Answer (score -2):

Another way is to use ledger lines. Ledger lines and different clefs (by octave or other transposition) are all common. One (supposedly) uses whatever is easiest to read.

A related complication is that some instruments are transposing; what you read (native to that instrument) isn't the note that sounds. (A clarinet or trumpet plays what that instrument calls a "C" and out comes a Bb or perhaps and A.)

Comment: This isn't really related to the question.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I disagree.  It is _related to_ the question.  But since the question is explicitly asking for a solution other than one using ledger lines, it certainly doesn't _answer_ the question.