# What does the 15 mean?

Tags: theory

[image]

What does the 15 mean in the image above?

Comment: This question may well revolve around the instrument that the music is played on. What would that be. Asking questions such as this, please bear in mind that more information is better than less.

Comment: @Tim Yes, sorry, its a piano piece.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the double octavia sign, it means that slide is to begin two octaves higher, see [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43950/how-to-write-very-high-low-notes-in-g-f-clef/43951#43951) question for further details

Comment: is "octavia" or "octava" correct here?

Comment: And it ought to have 'va' after it as well.

Comment: @Tim  I assume you mean the original notation should be  **15va** , right?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - yes, by itself, it's pretty meaningless. Va is higher, vb lower. Although it's fairly easy to guess it's two octaves higher, had it said 15va, probably the question would not have been posed.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - neither! *Ottava* - Italian.  And, sometimes, 'ma' for higher, 'mb' for lower. Why do things simply, when we can complicate them?

Comment: @Tim if anything, it should be *15ma,* but since *15* by itself is unambiguous, that's fine too.  The letters *va* do not mean *higher,* they are analogous to the *th* in *8th* as an abbreviation for *eighth.*  And I don't suppose that adding *ma* (nor *va)* would make it any clearer to someone who is unfamiliar with the notation.  So *8vb* and *15mb* are entirely spurious.  You'll never see an Italian composer using them.  Why complicate this with all the letters, anyway, when we could simply use the numbers *8* and *15*?  Up or down is indicated by the number's position above or below.